# Como recibir datos de un form a otro en oracle

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

¿Como se puede obtener en el FORMULARIO 2 los datos enviados del FORMULARIO 1?

```
/*FORMULARIO 1*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCEDURE PP_ABRIR_INDICACIONES(P_CLAVE_MEDICACION IN NUMBER) IS
pl_id PARAMLIST;
BEGIN
pl_id := GET_PARAMETER_LIST('ParamTemp');
IF NOT ID_NULL(pl_id) THEN
DESTROY_PARAMETER_LIST('ParamTemp');
END IF;
pl_id := CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST('ParamTemp');
IF ID_NULL(pl_id) THEN
pl_EXHIBIR_MENSAJE('Error al crear lista de parametros!');
END IF;

ADD_PARAMETER(pl_id,'P_CLAVE_NRO', TEXT_PARAMETER,TO_CHAR(P_CLAVE_MEDICACION));

ADD_PARAMETER(pl_id,'P_DESC_PROGRAMA',TEXT_PARAMETER, 'INDICACIONES');

OPEN_FORM('CONI004', ACTIVATE, SESSION, PL_ID);

END;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*FORMULARIO 2*/
```

Answer (score 1):

En el FORMULARIO2 debes crear los parámetros en el bloque `PARAMETER` con el mismo nombre con el que se envían `P_CLAVE_NRO` y `P_DESC_PROGRAMA` y luego se pueden usar en cualquier `program_unit` como `:PARAMETER.P_CLAVE_NRO`